# actionUrl not found. service : avContent

Tags: android

I'm developing app using remote sony camera sdk 2.40, I want to fetch recorded video video from sony camera sdcard.
It is providing below services:
1.guide
2.system
3.camera
4.accessControl

but the sdk that they have provide require avContent service to fetch data from sd card.
I'm using sony DSC-QX10 camera

Answer (score 0):

The 'Transfer Images' feature of the API is not supported on the QX10, according to:
https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/